# Hide ubuntu partition in win7

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, windows, ext4

I was searching forum but I didn't find solution to my problem.

I've installed Ubuntu 13.04 and Win7 on one HDD in UEFI mode. I'm able to boot in both OS'es separately from grub (added some entries). The problem is when I boot into Win7 I'm able to see Linux partition as RAW (in explorer, and only main partition, swap is hidden). When i double-click it then I'm asked to format this partition.

All I want to do is hide/unmount/not mounting it while booting system. Is it possible to do this?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: But this is not a question about Ubuntu. Is about Windows and how you can hide a partition. Try to use the partition management and remove the letter (ONLY the letter,not the entirely parititon).

Comment: Sorry but I didn't know where to ask it, and the problem is related with linux partiton. I'll try your suggestion and check if it works.

Comment: I absolutely *hate* how "purist" people are about questions like this. FFS it directly relates to Ubuntu, it just happens to be _more_ of a Windows question! As a mod, why not just move it over to SuperUser?!

Comment: @SamAndrew81 Chill man... Look at the date of this question. Since that day a lot has beem changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just as Hrishi mentioned... Here are a few screenshots.

Rightclick on Computer and Click in Manage:

[image]

On the left open *Disk Management*:

[image]

Then Rightclick on the Partition you want to hide and click *Change drive letter and Paths...*:

[image]

And finally mark the drive letter you want to remove and click *Remove*:
You will be prompted with warnings etc. just click on Yes.

[image]

The ubuntu Partition will now be hidden.

Comment: It really helps! Thank you all guys, now I'm able to use both systems without worries!

Answer (score 1):

Your Ubuntu partition must have a drive letter assigned to it in Windows 7. Go to `Disk Management` in Windows 7 and remove that drive letter. And you won't see it any longer.